# 502 returned when I try connect to my lumen api using nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, lumen

I have the following server blocks declared:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    root /var/www/mywebsite/frontend/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mywebsite/backend/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name api.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

That root directory in the second block is my Lumen php backend.
Now when I do a request to it like: http://api.mywebsite.com/categories then I get a 502 bad gateway issue.
How can I figure out what to do to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked NGINX's `error.log`?

Answer (score 0):

see this `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;` line...

investigate `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
that is using nginx user and or group, or www-data user and or group...

```
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock

listen.owner = nginx # www-data if you config nginx to use www-data user
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```